# Ставится ли запятая перед соединительным и разделительным союзами в сложносочиненном предложении из нескольких вопросительных частей?

Tags: пунктуация, ссп

**Что же такое слушание *(,)* и каковы его основные принципы *(,)* и какие приемы так называемого хорошего слушания необходимо усвоить каждому?**

Исходя из правила, что запятая перед соединительным и разделительным союзами в сложносочиненном предложении не ставится, если в его состав в качестве частей входят вопросительные предложения, каким образом в итоге, должна происходить расстановка запятых в данном предложение?

Есть ли примеры из классической литературы, где демонстрируется работа этого правила для предложения состоящего из нескольких вопросительных частей?

Answer (score 3):

Такое оформление не является удачным в плане стилистики (скорее всего, поэтому такого и нет в правилах). Первое И не кстати. Желательно так:
*Что же такое слушание, каковы его основные принципы и какие приемы так называемого хорошего слушания необходимо усвоить каждому?* || Эта пунктуация как раз и используется в исходном тексте.
https://userdocs.ru/literatura/3147/index.html?page=7

В этой теме у Розенталя есть лишь такое правило с повтором союза:
При наличии общего второстепенного члена предложения запятая перед союзом "и" ставится, если союз повторяется:
*В такую погоду и волк не рыщет, и медведь не вылезает из берлоги.

По дороге и пешеходы шли, и машины двигались нескончаемым потоком.

Как-то сразу и ветер усилился, и дождь пошел.*
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133

У Лопатина уже получше:
В сложносочиненном предложении с одиночными союзами *и*, *да* (в значении «и»), *или*, *либо* запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения представляют собой номинативные предложения. Однако если номинативных предложений больше, чем два, и союз и повторяется, то запятые ставятся — по правилу, которое действует при выделении однородных членов предложения.
http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg112.php

Это всё актуально и для вопросительных предложений.

Так что же делать в структуре с двумя И? В данном примере интонационно в одну фразу (вообще без запятых) оно никак не объединяется. Второе И точно должно быть присоединительным:
*Что же такое слушание и каковы его основные принципы, и какие приемы так называемого хорошего слушания необходимо усвоить каждому?*
Первое И тоже может быть присоединительным. Тогда получится перечисление трёх пунктов (вопросов) по отдельности. Это может быть связано с желанием сделать паузу перед каждым пунктом. А структура следующая:
*Такой вопрос, и ещё такой вопрос, и ещё такой вопрос.* || Нет объединения вопросительной интонацией.

Comment: А где вы тут увидели общий второстепенный член, можете подробнее рассказать?

Comment: Это из той же темы. Вместо общего элемента у нас вопросительная интонация (которая является общей).

Comment: Запятая перед соединительным и разделительным союзами в сложносочиненном предложении не ставится, если в его состав в качестве частей входят вопросительные предложения или объединяет вопросительная информация.
Я изначально сослался на это правило, но вы его отодвинули на задний план, и настояли на правиле с второстепенным членом предложения.
Я не согласен с тем, что в этом предложении есть второстепенный член, поэтому и уточняю у вас где вы его увидели.

Comment: Ничего не отодвигал. В том правиле нет речи о повторе союза. Привёл единственное правило этой темы, где повтор есть. Да нет у вас общего элемента.

Comment: Подправил эти моменты в ответе.

Answer (score 2):

1. Проблемный вопрос, просто детективная история. Вот исходный текст:
   *Что же такое слушание с психологической точки зрения, каковы его основные принципы и какие приемы так называемого хорошего слушания необходимо усвоить каждому?*
   https://studopedia.ru/14_78764_slushanie-kak-neobhodimoe-uslovie-effektivnoy-kommunikatsii.html

Это БСП,  здесь только один союз И, **но уж неверно поставлены знаки** – запятая перед союзом И нужна. По правилу Розенталя вопросительная интонация может связать **только два  предложения** одиночным союзом И. В этом случае они читаются в одну фонетическую фразу без обозначения паузы.

**И это всё, никаких других вариантов!** Некорректно переносить  на сложное предложение правила для однородных членов. Там одиночный союз И может связывать однородные члены **различным образом** (замыкающий союз, парное объединение), причем  **к вопросительной интонации** это не имеет отношения. **Однородным членам общий элемент для этого не нужен.**

2. Для этого предложения возможен такой вариант:  *Что же такое слушание с психологической точки зрения, какие основные принципы и приемы так называемого хорошего слушания необходимо усвоить каждому?* Такая форма  из двух предложений оптимально выражает содержание и подходит по стилю.

Но в заданном варианте три простых предложения, а зачем? По смыслу предложения  2 и 3 тесно связаны между собой. Да еще сомнительная во всех отношениях пунктуация (даже без учета основного правила) – с чего бы это общая вопросительная интонация будет объединять только два предложения  из трех? Ведь к первому предложению вопрос тоже относится.

3. Затем предложение  берут **для учебных целей**,  редактируют и получают  вариант  из заданного вопроса: ***Что же такое слушание, и каковы его основные принципы, и какие приемы так называемого хорошего слушания необходимо усвоить каждому?***

Здесь три предложения, **повторяющийся** союз И…И, поэтому запятые между простыми предложениями в  составе БСП **ставятся однозначно.**

Но стиль текста меняется. Использование повторяющегося союза И…И, перечислительная интонация для трех предложений – всё это кажется  необоснованным отступлением от делового стиля. Но для учебных целей предложение вполне подходит.

**Об обособлении сочетания «так называемые»**

Вопрос № 216574  [http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=так%20называемый&start=30](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9&start=30)

Дорогая Справка, подскажите, пожалуйста, выделяется ли запятыми выражение "так называемый".

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Сами по себе слова "так называемый" запятыми не выделяются, но может выделяться оборот, который присоединяется с их помощью.

Comment: У Розенталя есть два примера с более чем двумя элементами: *У Гаврилы смешно надулись щёки, оттопырились губы и суженные глаза как-то чересчур часто и смешно помаргивали* (М. Г.). *Тишина, темнота, одиночество и этот странный шум* (Симонов). У Лопатина один: *К полудню черные облака почти коснутся земли, задует сырой ветер и польются томительные, нагоняющие сон обложные дожди* (Пауст.) Запятой перед И нет, хотя, по вашей логике, она должна стоять. При вопросительной интонации должно происходить то же самое (с тремя элементами), да и в одну фразу (без ударения перед И) оно вполне читается.

Comment: Что ж, замечание принято.  Могу сказать, что  три предложения встречаются отнюдь НЕ ЧАСТО. Что касается вопросительной интонации, то  она в качестве общего элемента для трех предложений выглядит особенно СОМНИТЕЛЬНО. Недаром это предложение стали ПРАВИТЬ, чтобы оно подошло для учебного примера.

Comment: Предлагаю написать к правилам Розенталя следующее ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ. Обычно союз И/ИЛИ соединяет два простых предложения, при этом паузы между ними нет, что соответствует отсутствию запятой.  Реже одиночный союз И  может быть замыкающим при перечислении простых предложений, например:  К ПОЛУДНЮ черные облака почти коснутся земли, задует сырой ветер и польются томительные, нагоняющие сон обложные дожди. Также отметим, что восклицательная или вопросительная интонация обычно связывает только ДВА простых предложения в составе ССП (в правилах Розенталя или ПАС таких примеров нет).

Comment: Да, согласен. Странно, что Розенталь ничего не сказал про количество более 2 — он обычно просчитывал все ситуации. В одном оригинальном справочнике Розенталя в этих пунктах прямо и написано число 2 (хотя там же дан пример с 4 элементами, который есть выше, что выглядит как просчёт), но он один из самых ранних, а в следующих редакциях количество уже не стали ограничивать. А два И в 1 вопр. предложении крайне неудачно стилистически. Это чисто разговорный стиль, когда новые вопросы приходят через "поток мыслей"(*вот это, и ещё вот это, ну и ещё это тоже*), или же человек их постепенно вспоминает.

Comment: Мне кажется, что с союзом  И...И связана ненужная экспрессия, которая для публицистики больше подходит.

Comment: Не знаю, для меня оно звучит дико в связи с научной тематикой, где всё систематизировано (а не "поток сознания"). Его же изменили, оно не должно быть с двумя И.

Comment: oleedd, вы думаете союзом И...И обозначают только поток сознания? Это вполне серьезный союз со своей областью применения. http://rusgram.ru/Сочинительные_союзы#231   2.1. Повторяющиеся союзы: семантика

Comment: Здесь не И... И (который начинается **перед первым** элементом), а два отдельных И.

Comment: Это почему же? Просто в этом случае И повторяется со второго предложения. Кстати,  интонация перечислительная для всех.

Comment: Да нет, оно бы с первого начиналось (*и вчера, и сегодня, и завтра ему нужно...*), этот союз употребляется **перед каждым** элементом. По вашей ссылке: ***каждый** конъюнкт участвует в сочинении; **каждый** конъюнкт рассматривается отдельно*.

Comment: А если первый конъюнкт пропущен, то это уже поток сознания, да? Интересное мнение, мне нравится :)

Comment: Я ориентируюсь на то, как говорят люди, а не на теорию. Пример: *вчера, и сегодня, и завтра...* Здесь запятая перед первым И в связи с паузой из-за того, что мысль пришла позже или человек потом припомнил что-то. Когда И перед каждым элементом, то ничего не приходит и не вспоминается, а просто каждый элемент подчёркивается.

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже столкнулась с таким заданием и в интернете нашла такой вариант:

> Что же такое слушание`,` и каковы его основные принципы и какие приемы
> так называемого хорошего слушания необходимо усвоить каждому?

Но так же я нашла похоже по составу предложения где ВСЕ вопросительные части отделяются запятыми, то есть имеет место быть такая запись:

> Что же такое слушание`,` и каковы его основные принципы`,` и какие приемы
> так называемого хорошего слушания необходимо усвоить каждому?

Но, если честно, я сама не могу дать верного ответа. Только тот, что в интернете, а в интернете уйма опечаток

UPD: ВЫ ЩА УПАДЕТЕ!
Мне данное задание попалось в ВИ из МИРЭА и сегодня была апелляция, на которой мне сказали, что грамотное написание такое:

> Что же такое слушание`,` и каковы его основные принципы`,` и какие приемы
> `,`так называемого`,` хорошего слушания необходимо усвоить каждому?

Сказать, что я в ауте - ничего не сказать. Мне не удалось отбить баллы за то что они решили ввести "так называемого" в разряд вводного слова...

Возможно я чего-то не знаю, может вы мне подскажите)