# "Так называемые" - вводное слово, а также выделение вопросительных предложений запятыми

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Нашла такое предложение в задании:

> Что же такое слушание и каковы его основные принципы и какие приемы
> так называемого хорошего слушания необходимо усвоить каждому?

Нужно правильно расставить запятые. Я, зная правило о расстановке запятых между двумя вопросительными предложениями без главной части, расставила так:

> Что же такое слушание`,` и каковы его основные принципы`,` и какие приемы
> так называемого хорошего слушания необходимо усвоить каждому?

Но, загуглив, увидела такой вариант:

> Что же такое слушание`,` и каковы его основные принципы и какие приемы
> так называемого хорошего слушания необходимо усвоить каждому?

Вопрос №1: какая правильная расстановка запятых и по какому правилу?

---

Мне данное задание попалось в ВИ из МИРЭА и сегодня была апелляция, на которой мне сказали, что грамотное написание такое:

> Что же такое слушание`,` и каковы его основные принципы`,` и какие приемы
> `,`так называемого`,` хорошего слушания необходимо усвоить каждому?

Сказать, что я в ауте - ничего не сказать. Мне не удалось отбить баллы за то что они решили ввести "так называемого" в разряд вводного слова, когда оно таковым не является. Объяснили, что тут задействовано какое-то невидимое волшебное правило, которое пишут только в очень старых, редких и безумно мудрых книжках, названий которых никто, естественно, не помнит. Назвали его вводным словом отрицания (хотя я отрицания здесь никакого не вижу) и сказали, что разговор на том закончен.

Вопрос №2: а в каких ситуациях может обособляться запятыми "так называемого", ну или являться вводным словом?

Возможно, я чего-то не знаю, может, вы мне подскажете?)

Comment: Можете предоставить в вопросе ссылки на найденные варианты и правило, зная которое вы расставили запятые?

Answer (score 1):

Ни в коем случае не сдавайтесь! "Так называемый" здесь однозначно не обособляется. Правильно:

***Что же такое слушание, и каковы его основные принципы, и какие приемы так называемого хорошего слушания необходимо усвоить каждому?***

Существует правило, согласно которому запятая не ставится в сложносочинённом предложении между двумя вопросительными предложениями. Но здесь три простых предложения, и в этом случае знаки ставятся между частями ССП как при однородных членах.

Comment: Вот именно, как при однородных членах (об этом сказано у Лопатина, но в другом пункте), тогда первая запятая не нужна. В правиле не указано, что частей может быть лишь две.

Comment: Мой ответ обновлен: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467027

Comment: Возражаю. Нужна первая запятая,oleedd.  Ср.: Маша, и Даша. и Света. После первого элемента запятая тоже ставится, даже если перед ним нет союза И.

Comment: Тогда зачем говорить об однородных членах? И вариант с одной запятой тоже допустим — как присоединение третьего вопроса к двум, соединённым вопросительной интонацией.

Comment: Есть такое правило(у того же Розенталя), что если есть однородные члены, соединенные повторяющимися союзами, и перед первым однородным нет повторяющегося союза, то запятая перед первым повторяющимся союзом ставится.

Comment: Есть возможность объединения в группу. Лопатин: *И голубой дымок, и первых встреч неясная тревога, и на плечи наброшенный платок, казенный дом и дальняя дорога* (Сим.) (в последней части — *казенный дом и дальняя дорога* — запятой нет, так как эта часть воспринимается как единое целое.